# How to say that something is worthy

Tags: expressions

In this sentence:

> We design to create a world in human dignity and as possible

I want to say that we design to make a world that is worthy for humans to live in, as possible as **it is**.

"As possible as it is" means: Our abilities are limited. So we may can't do something ideally, but it is still worthy because we have used all of the current possibilities. I want to say that's not about quality to use "good" instead.

I have used translators. Is it true to say this that way?
Does it mean anything, after all?
What the better sentence ?

**Edit:**
How about this one ?

> We design to create a world that is worthy for human to live in, and
>   as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, "as possible as it is" is unnecessary. It's already implied. Also, "create a world" sounds more like we're designing a new game, where we can create as many alternate worlds as we want to. The phrase "make the world a better place" is more idiomatic.

So, I would like to offer this:

> **We design to make the world worth living in.**
>   We design to make our world worth living in.

If you want to emphasize that what you can do is limited, you might say:

> We design to make the world as worth living in as possible.
>   We design to make the world worth living in, and as much as possible.

But that sounds a little wordy, and a little clumsy.

If you want to emphasize that you will do everything that you can do, you can also say:

> We design to make the world worth living in, every way we can.

But that might not be what you really wanted to say.

Comment: I think the 3rd or 4th sentence is Ok. Why didn't you mention the human?

Comment: I think "human" is implied already (by saying the world, which we're all living in). The same goes to "the world". "The world" also implies "our world", this world, our Earth.

Comment: In the interests of further simplifying the sentence, how about "We aim to make our world worth living in"?

Comment: @nxx I like that. However, I think the OP's *design* might need to be preserved because it sounds like it's about a design mission, as in a slogan for a design company, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "We design to create a world in human dignity and as possible" makes little sense in English, and its end is outright ungrammatical — it appears as if you cut it off in the middle. Do not use it.

Your explanation of what it is you are trying to say is much better: "We design to make a world that is worthy for human to live in, as possible as we can". It still has a couple mistakes, though: *humans* should be plural, and "as possible as we can" is ungrammatical, it should be "as good as we can" (a more idiomatical altermative still would be "to the best of our abilities").

The sentence is still a bit clumsy overall, but there are any number of possible rewordings, and which one is the best is in the eye of the beholder. I am specifically not starting a list here, so as not to turn this into a subjective and argumentative question.

Comment: How about this one:
We design to create a world as much as possible to be worthy for humans to live in

Answer (score 0):

"[inasmuch as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inasmuch+as)" may sound old-fashioned, but it seems a good match as you are speaking of rather lofty ideas, and I think it goes well with words like "worthy" and "design":

> We design to create a world that is worthy of humans, inasmuch as we
>   are able.

If you want something more straightforward and less poetic, then you could try:

> We aim to create a world deserving of humans, to the extent that that is possible.